# Two independent events

Tags: probability

For two independent events $A$ and $B$

We know $P(A\cap B)  = P(A).P(B)$.

Here what does this '$P(A\cap B)$' signifies?

And for these events what does this $P(A\cup B)$ signifies?

If possible explain with an example.

Comment: You have been exposed to the notion of independence of events but you cannot decipher the expressions P(A∩B) and P(A∪B)? Sorry but this is not making any sense.

Comment: @Did perahaps their instructor used these stmbols and forgot to explain them

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the probability of the intersection of independent events $A$ and $B$ is the product of their probabilities is actually the definition of independent events.

An example maybe: Suppose the probability of a person being left handed is $\frac{1}{5}$ and that of being blue-eyed is $\frac{1}{3}$. The intersection of these two events is thus being "left handed and blue eyed". If the events are independent, the proportion of blue-eyed people among the left-handed people is the same as the proportion of blue-eyed people among the whole population, i.e. $\frac{1}{3}$. Thus $\frac{1}{3}$ of $\frac{1}{5}$ or $\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{15}$ is thus both left handed and blue eyed.

Answer (score 1):

Events are sets of outcomes.    $\cap, \cup$ are *set operators*, representing *intersection* and *union* respectively; which should be familiar from primary school; recall set theory, Venn Diagrams, and such.

> Here what does this 'P(A∩B)' signifies?

The probability that events $A$ *and* $B$ occur.   The probability that the outcome is in the *intersection* of events $A, B$

> And for these events what does this 'P(A∪B)'
>   signifies?

The probability that events $A$ *or* $B$ occur.  The probability that the outcome is in the *union* of events $A, B$.

Comment: Can you explain with an example

Answer (score 0):

In general A∩B is the group with all elements that are both in A and in B. 
So here P(A∩B) signifies the probability that both events A and B happen. 
P(A∪B) signifies the probability that either even A or event B or both happen.

A and B being independent means intuitively that they do not affect each other- for example if A is the event "today is Friday" and B is the event "it rained yesterday".
So in cases like this we get that the probability that both A and B happen is 
 P(A∩B) = P(A)*P(B)

Comment: And what does P(A$\cup$B )means

Comment: If you believe that rain and the day of the week are independent, [please reconsider](http://io9.gizmodo.com/this-is-why-it-always-rains-on-weekends-1540233798).